# Can I mark duplicates over different SE sites?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

By nature [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) overlap in their subject. So there may be situations, where a question asked on SO may be answered on programmers, vice versa.

In fact [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475427/singleton-or-static-what-should-i-use) question has been already answered [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141147/static-class-vs-singleton-class-in-c) (for as far as I understood it).

So my questions are:

1. Should such cases are "marked as duplicate" (in any way) at all?
2. If yes, should I do this using the "inform moderator / other" flag?
3. If not, is there another way, I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172307/187824

Comment: I don't want to search all stackexchange sites before asking a question.. It is impossible..

Comment: Leave a comment with a link to the duplicate, then vote/flag to close as off topic.