# How to handle duplicates on other sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Simple example: [better way to import java script files and css files using CDN or from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209770/better-way-to-import-java-script-files-and-css-files-using-cdn-or-from-local-mac)

The exact duplicate is on programmers.se: [Referencing external javascript vs. hosting my own copy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139372/referencing-external-javascript-vs-hosting-my-own-copy)

However, SO won't allow me to flag the other as a duplicate because it's on another site. I don't want to close as off-topic; should be on programmers.se, because it might lead the asker to post his question on programmers.se or a mod to move the question over there.

Adding a comment + closing as off-topic is the best thing I can think of, but it feels "incomplete".

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, we don't like cross-posting. Flag for moderator attention with a link. Though if the question is indeed off-topic on one of the sites, you should vote to close as such.

Comment: @Oded Neither question is off topic on their respective sites. It happens.

Comment: I once asked a similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172329/can-i-mark-duplicates-over-different-se-sites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment you've already left pointing to the Programmers version is enough.

The Stack Overflow version of the question is *not* off topic for Stack Overflow, closing it just because a very similar question exists on another site wouldn't make much sense. The sites overlap a bit in expertise, some questions are perfectly on topic on both. However, there's a [very good duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai) of it right here on Stack Overflow, so it won't really stay open for long.

If the question was completely off topic on Stack Overflow, flagging for moderation attention and asking for it to be migrated would have been appropriate. Assuming the moderators agreed with your flag, your comment would have quickly pointed us to the duplicate once the question reached our shores.

Comment: Thanks. So the procedure is to move it, then let it be closed as duplicate on the other site.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yes. Now, if the question hasn't gotten any answers yet, it might make sense to let the OP know that they can simply delete it and save everyone the trouble (assuming of course the question on the other site is an _exact_ dupe).

Answer (score 0):

My best quess is that you should flag the question with `it needs ♦ moderator attention` and the in the `other` section you could provide the link of the duplicate question so the moderator can look at it. You should also leave a comment on the question linking to the programmers.se question and telling him that such questions belong on that site.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the current solution of "just put a link in the comments" is wrong for two reasons.

Firstly anyone digging through to answer old questions will stumble upon it as an unanswered question and may start working on a solution. Yes I know we should all read the comments but the fact of the matter when you look up the question it states "0 answers" which is false.

Secondly, and this is the more important case, when users are seeking answers and perform a search they too will see "0 answers". This makes the site less user friendly. Its bad enough that people tend to answer questions in the comments section, do we really need to force people to do it now?

Why wouldn't you allow from cross site answers when you already allow for duplicates. When something is flagged duplicate its not instantly deleted. Its flagged, a note is put on it stating its a duplicate an users can see see it and navigate to a solution. The current "solution" feels more like a work around for the fact that the site has a bug (sites can't communicate with each other), rather than being an actual solution. If more sites are going to be added with specific scope (see how there is vi.se and emacs.se and yet there are tons of so.se posts that already answered their questions), this really should be resolved much better. Otherwise you're going to have lots of duplicate effort or lots of questions with no answers.