# What is the recommended way to handle questions that are duplicates of questions in a different SE site?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

If you have an SO question A that is a duplicate of question B on SO, it should be closed as such. However, what if question B lives not on SO but on, say, vi.SE?

As far as I know there is no option to *close as duplicate* in such a case, but is there a common way how this is or should be handled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate questions on other SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/), see also [How to handle duplicates on other sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185154/398063)

Comment: I agree. I didn't find these earlier.